# Custom delimiters in MS SQL Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server

I have to export data to a csv file. But requirement is that Record Separator should be Ctrl^ (char 30) and column separator should be Ctrl_ (char 31).
The Export wizard in SQL Server (2014) does not allow for these characters. There are only predefined options {CR}{LF}, {CR}, {LF}, semicolon etc.

How I can provide custom delimiters?

Comment: The SSMS export wizard generates an SSIS package that can be edited with [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16). You can use whatever character you want as the field delimiter. SSDT contains the same wizard as SSMS which can be used to quickly generate the package

Comment: BTW SQL Server 2014 is no longer in mainstream support. The oldest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: *"does not allow for these characters"* Yes it does. [Just type them in the boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHXOp.png)... (I assume by "record" you mean row; "record" has no meaning in SQL Server, and I have seen it used to reference values, rows columns, and groups of rows that share a single identifier.)

Comment: @Larnu, great. How can I type char(31 or 30) from keyboard?

Comment: `SELECT CHAR(31),CHAR(30)`. *Select appropriate Cell* `Ctrl`+`c`. *Select Drop down* `Ctrl`+`v`.

Comment: SELECT CHAR(31),CHAR(30) shows empty cells.

Comment: But they aren't, @CFML_Developer . As you are well aware, those characters aren't printable, but that doesn't mean they aren't there... I wouldn't have told you to do the above if it doesn't work: I literally did it and exported a [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrXcN.png) doing so before I told you to copy and paste the characters.